# R "combinations" function and "options" command

Tags: r

I would like to use the `combinations()` function of the `gtools` package. However, since the number of combinations I  need is very large, there are memory issues to circumvent. The R documentation says to increase the value of the "expressions" argument of the "options" command and, in addition, to "start R with a larger protection stack".

Does anyone have experience doing this sort of thing? I don't want mess with memory if it might have bad side effects.

From the R documentation:

> Note too that you may cause a segfault from overflow of the C stack,
>   and on OSes where it is possible you may want to increase that.